# DB2 table access list

Tags: db2

i want to find db2 tables access list(which user or program has privilige which table). how can i query this? 
If i would write this psedue code i wil be like this.

```
select table's_grant_user_name from sysibm.... where table_name='XXX'`
```

is there any ibm `privillige table` been in db2?

In aqt tool i can see tables access list when i select from combobox. But i need this query to querying for some tables to groupping.
is it possible to query this ? how can i retrieve table's grant list?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the view [SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/c0061231.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0&lang=en).

Comment: It might be easier to use [`SYSCAT.TABAUTH`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001061.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-8-103&lang=en) which is specific to tables only. @altangodan Please note that neither method can list _implicitly granted_ privileges, e.g. from being the table owner or having the `DATAACCESS` privilege.